# JQuery image gallery non functional fade effects

Tags: jquery, effects, image-gallery

Here is a simple image gallery script for fading in and out divs with background images. It is slow and not working properly.

- It would appear all images are appearing and disappearing together without any animation
- This gallery should fade each image out into the next one

  ```
  function gallery() {
              timerp = window.setInterval(function() {
                  $('.cornerimg').fadeOut(2000);

                  if ($('.cornerimg:visible') == $('.cornerimg').last()) {
                      $('.cornerimg').first().fadeIn(2000);
                  } else {
                      $('.cornerimg').next().fadeIn(2000);
                  };
              }, 6000);
          }
  }
  ```

Any ideas what has gone wrong with it?

Comment: There's about a zillion great jQuery gallery scripts out there and nearly all have many transition effects built in.  Why are you re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Because it is a backup function for a CSS3 transition gallery that works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next()` just finds the next sibling for the selector. It doesn't keep track of where you are. I would do a setInterval and pass the current index along with it. For example:

```
function gallery() {
        ind = 0;
        l = $('.cornerimg').length;
        $('.cornerimg').fadeOut(500);        

        window.setInterval( function() {
            if ( ind > 0 ) $('.cornerimg').eq(ind-1).fadeOut(2000);
            if (ind == l) {
                ind = 0;
            }
            $('.cornerimg').eq(ind).fadeIn(500);
            ind++;
        }, 2000 );
}

$(function() { gallery() });
```

To avoid shifting of elements, add the function as a callback to the `fadeOut` instead of having them happen asynchronously.

NOTE: Global variables are not the best way to go in general, but just to give you an idea. The better form is to have a function that calls itself with `setTimeout` and passes the incremented ind argument each time.

UNTESTED.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. This function is working perfectly with CSS3 transitions and addClass. I see not why it works so badly in JQUery.

Comment: Thanks, but that animation is not on a loop at all. Try it yourself. I decreased the times to speed it up http://jsfiddle.net/qUvxh/1/

Comment: That works in the fiddle but not on our webpage. Maybe you can see the problem it makes no sense to me at all -- http://www.golfbrowser.com/courses/wentworth-east/ but make sure you go in a browser that does not support CSS3 as there is already a functioning CSS3 gallery.

Comment: Fix your iscroll.js problem and then we can look at the page cleanly. (Needs attachEvent instead of addEventListener for IE < 9.)

Comment: done ... try it now. That has blown my iScroll function though for scrollable divs on touchscreen devices

Comment: It needs to be `attachEvent`, not `attachEvents`, and only IE < 9 needs this, so you should do browser detection to determine whether to do `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`.

Comment: It's kind of a mess in there, and I don't have time to wade through it all. Make sure the call to gallery() is in a document.ready wrapper, and remove the old gallery function so that there aren't two functions with the same name. If it doesn't work after that, you're on your own! The jsFiddle works, so it's just a matter of fitting it into your own code...

Comment: There is not an old function. One function is triggered by CSS transitions. If the browser does not support that then the other function is triggered instead