# JQuery image gallery working in JSFiddle but not on website

Tags: jquery, class, effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery image gallery non functional fade effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536077/jquery-image-gallery-non-functional-fade-effects)

I have built a CSS3 image gallery that defaults to a standard JQuery gallery when no CSS is found. This JQuery gallery is not working.

The CSS gallery is governed by adding and removing classes using JQUery with transition effects on those classes.

I thought the JQuery one should work the same with the UI ability to animate the add remove class. It does not. Its jumpy and does not animate much of the time.

The CSS classes govern the opacity of the varius divs. The code is below but I suggest looking at the example page in a browser that does not support CSS3 to see that is going wrong. http://www.golfbrowser.com/courses/wentworth-east/

If anyone can work this one out before madness I would be greatly appreciative.

```
var timerp = null;
        var nextslide;


        if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
            $('.thumbs').click(function() {
        if (timerp) {
            window.clearInterval(timerp);
        }
        $('.cornerimgfocus').removeClass('cornerimgfocus',2000);
        $('#P' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('cornerimgfocus',2000);   gallery() 
    });
        function gallery() {
            timerp = window.setInterval(function() {
                var islide = $('.cornerimgfocus');
                islide.removeClass('cornerimgfocus',2000);

                if (islide[0] == $('.cornerimg:last')[0]) {
                    nextslide =  $('.cornerimg').first();
                } else {
                    nextslide = islide.next();
                };
                nextslide.addClass('cornerimgfocus',2000);
            }, 6000);
        }
}
```

Comment: If it's working in JSFiddle but not your site, perhaps it's conflicting with another script.  Remove all others and try it again.  Put them back one by one until the problem returns.